# How to select a default option of a dropdownList in Yii framework 2.0

Tags: php, list, select, yii2

Below is my code snippet of Yii framework 2.0 ActiveField/DropdownList

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();

    foreach ($settings as $index => $setting) {

        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
             echo $form->field($setting, "[$index]option[]")->dropdownList(['0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => 'C']) ?>
        }
    }

ActiveForm::end();
```

With the for loop above I have a dynamic set of models within a form and each model has 3 dropdownLists of the same property `option` which can be submitted as an array. When `$i = 0` I would like to select option `A` as default. When `$i = 1` I would like to select option `B` as default and When `$i = 2` I would like to select option `C` as default.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) 
    {
        $model->option[$i] = "$i";
        echo $form->field($model, "option[$i]")
             ->dropdownList(['0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => 'C']);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

echo $form->dropDownList(

```
$model,

'country_id',

Country::items(),

array(
    'empty'=>'--Select a country--')
);
```